# Plotly: How to plot multiple lines with shared x-axis?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to have a multiple line plot within same canvas tied with the same x-axis as shown something in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TeiR.png):

[image]

Using subplots does not achieve the intended desire.

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, shared_xaxes=True,vertical_spacing=0.1)
fig.add_scatter(y=[2, 1, 3], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_scatter(y=[1, 3, 2], row=2, col=1)
fig.show()
```

May I know how this can be done, appreciate if someone can point to good reading material

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a dataset such as [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv) you can select any number of columns, set up a figure using `fig = make_subplots()` with `shared_xaxes` set to `True` and then add your series with a shared x-axis using `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[col].index, y=df[col].values), row=i, col=1)` in a loop to get this:

[image]

Let me know if this is a setup you can use but need a little tweaking.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

# data
pio.templates.default = "plotly_white"
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.tail()
cols = df.columns[:-4]
ncols = len(cols)

# subplot setup
fig = make_subplots(rows=ncols, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

for i, col in enumerate(cols, start=1):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[col].index, y=df[col].values), row=i, col=1)
    
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the data you are plotting, I think you could either check out "Stacked Subplots with a Shared X-Axis (low-level API)" on https://plotly.com/python/subplots/

Or separate the data by shifting each line plot upwards like so:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random


data = []
n = 9

for x in range(10, 60, 10):

  points = [value + x for value in random.sample(range(1,n+1), k = n)]
  
  data.append(go.Scatter(y=points))

fig = go.Figure(data = data)

fig.show()
```